# Colorize specific region in plane

Tags: plotting, graphics

The plane is divided into a grid and points is distributed on it.

```
num = 100;
r = N[1/20];
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}];
fig = ListPlot[points, GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, r], Range[0, 1, r]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  ImageSize -> 1000]
```

I am interested in colorizing specific regions in the plane.

```
fig2 = Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.7`, 0.4`}, {0.75`, 0.45`}}]
Show[fig2, fig]
```

But someting go wrong, any sugestion on how to do it correct? Aditionlly how to extend it to few squares in plane?

Comment: The problem is that options in the first item in `Show` override options given in the later ones. In this case, the settings for axes and gridlines are taken from `fig2`, i.e. are not included at all. The plot range of `fig2` becomes the plot range for the combined figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
num = 100;
r = N[1/20];
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}];
coord = {{0.7`, 0.4`}, {0.75`, 0.45`}};
fig = ListPlot[points,
  GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, r], Range[0, 1, r]},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3.5},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  ImageSize -> 1000
  , Epilog -> {{Green, Opacity[.5], Rectangle @@ coord}}
  ]
```

> [image]